# Deserialize c# with BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I am trying to save and load in c# with serialization. However, I am having troubles with loading and I am not sure I understand where the problem is. Here is the code:

```
 [Serializable]
public class Network : ISerializable
{
    private static readonly string _FILE_PATH = "Network.DAT";

    //properties
    public List<Component> MyComponents { get; private set; }
    public List<Pipeline> Pipelines { get; private set; }

    public Network()
    {
        this.MyComponents = new List<Component>();
        this.Pipelines = new List<Pipeline>();
    }
    public Network(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.MyComponents = (List<Component>)info.GetValue("MyComponents", MyComponents.GetType());
        this.Pipelines = (List<Pipeline>)info.GetValue("Pipelines", Pipelines.GetType());
    }
    **//Methods**
    public static void SaveToFile(Network net)
    {
        using (FileStream fl = new FileStream(_FILE_PATH, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binFormatter.Serialize(fl,net );
        }
    }
    public static Network LoadFromFile()
    {
        FileStream fl = null;
        try
        {
            fl = new FileStream(_FILE_PATH, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter binF = new BinaryFormatter();
            return (Network)binF.Deserialize(fl);

        }
        catch
        {
            return new Network();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fl != null)
            {
                fl.Close();
            }
        }
    }

   public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("MyComponents", MyComponents);

        info.AddValue("Pipelines", Pipelines);

    }
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ClassDiagram-Final.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
public Network(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    this.MyComponents = (List<Component>)info.GetValue("MyComponents", MyComponents.GetType());
    this.Pipelines = (List<Pipeline>)info.GetValue("Pipelines", Pipelines.GetType());
}
```

This is so called the deserialization constructor, and as with any constructor, the members of the class are not initialized, so `MyComponents.GetType()` and `Pipelines.GetType()` cannot be used (produce NRE).

You can use something like this instead

```
public Network(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    this.MyComponents = (List<Component>)info.GetValue("MyComponents", typeof(List<Component>));
    this.Pipelines = (List<Pipeline>)info.GetValue("Pipelines", typeof(List<Pipeline>));
}
```

Comment: Well, that worked. I got rid of the error. Now I am loading the saved file and its not actually loaded. Nothing is changed and my lists remain empty.

Comment: Hmm, an you are sure they were not empty when saving? Also not going thru `catch { return new Network(); }` branch?

Comment: Fixed that. Now im getting this An exception of type     'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Member 'ComponentBox' was not found.

Comment: Unfortunately this goes far beyond the scope of the OP. Binary serialization is a tricky thing because all the involved classes must support proper serialization. You need to check all the classes (`Component` and derived, `Pipeline`) and their members. I would suggest you activating the Exception setting (something like `Break When Exception is thrown") and examine the call stack to see which class/member is throwing the exception. Then see the source code of that class etc.

Comment: I am doing that now. Its a loong process tho. Thank you for your input.